# TypeError: semrush.backlinks_refdomains is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sails.js

Guys when i was trying to get data from SEMRUSH API https://www.semrush.com/api-analytics/#domain_rank  using backlinks_refdomains and backlinks_refips its showing me this error.

And when i called same function domain_rank it responded me in json format. can you help me out in this. Attached image is the result when is is give me domain_rank but not other factors like baclinks and etc.
I am using this code.

```
`

module.exports = {
index: function(req,res){

    console.log("Hello welocme!");
    var SEMRushAPI = require('sails-semrush');
    var URL = "www.flipkart.com";
    var database = {database:'us'};
    var semrush = new SEMRushAPI('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

semrush.backlinks(URL, database, function(err, response){
if (err){

        console.log("There is some error to fetching web traffic on API !");
        console.log("err: ",err);
        console.log("There is some error to fetching web traffic on API !");
        }else{
                 console.log("backlinks");
            console.log(" Response: ",response);
            console.log("**************** Get the web traffic successfully ***************");
            console.log("******zone, country, ip*******");
        } 

semrush.backlinks_refdomains(URL, database, function(err, response){ 
          if (err){

        console.log("There is some error to fetching web traffic on API !");
        console.log("err: ",err);
        console.log("There is some error to fetching web traffic on API !");
        }else{

console.log("domain_score_asc, domain_score_desc, backlinks_asc, backlinks_desc, last_seen_asc, last_seen_desc, first_seen_asc, first_seen_desc");
console.log(" Response: ",response);
console.log("**************** Get the web traffic successfully **************");
console.log("zone, country, ip");
}
});
```

`

[This is image of my output, where i getting domain ranks but not backlinks can some one help me in this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrjGg.png)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

DO you try close () for function?

There are missed brackets ')':

1) semrush.backlinks(URL, database, function(err, response) {

Try fix it:
semrush.backlinks(URL, database, function(err, response)){

2) semrush.backlinks_refdomains(URL, database, function(err, response) {

Try fix it:
semrush.backlinks_refdomains(URL, database, function(err, response)){

Comment: Hello thanks for response                                                                                                       i tried working with your code as well but it did not worked!          Error its shows : 
          TypeError: semrush.backlinks_refdomains is not a function

Comment: If I right understand, manually it's worked well, but in code is not?


In this case you should ask developers of 'sails-semrush' why does it happen. 

How I saw you already get answer for your question from their side 
> https://github.com/scott-wyatt/sails-semrush/issues/2

Comment: and there is no problem with the brackets if it would be it should give error like SyntaxError: Unexpected token but in my case its giving different. that means my code is fine

Comment: Yes @ivan but with node-semrush also its not responding, process of calling API is same in bith cases according to your documentation. But in other factors its responding but not backlinks

Comment: Hello ivan did you figured out what is the problem. Though i have called API with both trhe process. but still standing in same page.

Comment: I have just count brackets and found that 
'{' - 9 times, '}' - 6 times, '(' - 24 times, ')' - 23 times.

It means that:  three '}' and one ')' were lost.

I can't believe that this code can work in this state. ( I tried to find some examples with it on https://www.w3schools.com/js/ and http://nodeguide.com/style.html but nothing found about missed brackets)
Can you update your code example up to correct state?

Comment: I hope this link contain code which have equally number of brackets in both the end. but it still shows domain_rank_history is not a function its show aan error again, this is the link which have the code.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900901/typeerror-semrush-domain-rank-history-is-not-a-function